# How do I find a bigger battery for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an ASUS K42JR laptop, and the battery life in this thing sucks (2 hours max). I'd like to get a bigger battery for it,  and I've found a bunch online, but I have no idea which one fits/works with my laptop.

Any idea how I can find that out?

Comment: shopping questions such as where-do-I-buy and what-should-I-pay are offtopic on Super User, so i've edited that out of your post.

Comment: Hello. I also have same kind laptop as you have for now. It's 2020, I use it since 2011. It kinda suck. ASUS don't want to admit they sell a defected laptop that can't run nvidia optimus that lead to massive battery drain for nvidia run each time, which is sad! So Til today. Yeah. It still use 4400mah battery and only last about 2.5 hours when first time usage, with wifi, and near 3 hours without wifi on windows 10 20H2. Sucks. Yeah, is there anyway arround it? No. Sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most places where they sell batteries online tell you which models they support.  You typically search by manufacturer and model. Also if you go to a local store that sells batteries such as Batteries Plus you can bring them your laptop and they will be able to find the proper battery.

However I actually don't believe that Asus makes a extended battery for this laptop.  All of the websites I visited only sell the standard 6 cell 4400 mAh battery.  An extended battery for a laptop of this size would be a 8 or 9 cell battery with around 5600 mAh.

You can also ask Asus directly by filling out a Technical Inquiry From http://support.asus.com/techserv/techserv.aspx
to see if they make an extended battery for your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an indication of which laptops the battery will fit on the site. If you post some links that would help.

The things to check are:

a) it has the same connection as your current battery
b) it's the same physical size as your current battery

Having said that, there are some laptops that can accept an external battery and I've known of cases where you could replace the optical drive with another battery. You will need to check your laptop's specs to see if either of these apply.

*Thanks quack for reminding me about these cases*

Comment: Side note: For many business laptops there are batteries with more cells (= longer battery life = larger battery), so the same dimensions aren't strictly necessary (in the general case). However, for many consumer laptops or subnotebooks those aren't an option and you're stuck with exactly one size.